# Ionic framework installing issue

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, command

[image]

I install node js then i put the command on prompt 'npm install -g ionic'

but i am facing issue ionic is not install properly in my system can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You are using old version of NodeJS (4.4.6), Ionic needs for proper functioning at least `node >= 6.4.0`. As stated in log information.

Try installing newer version.

Comment: @VikasPareek glad I could help :) if this resolved your issue, please mark my answer as approved

Comment: How can approved your answer sorry i'm new in stackoverflow.

Comment: @VikasPareek take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/tour it will show you some basic things about SO, near the up/down vote arrows you will be able to click green checkmark :) In tour: "The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted"."

Answer (score 1):

you are using a old node version. Please update Your node version. also make sure you install a LTS version. you can check your node version with this command

```
node --version
```

https://nodejs.org/en/